# Help inequality real numbers

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, optimization, linear-programming

I'm currently reading the book "The Design of Approximation Algorithms". In page 25, they introduce Fact 1.10 and use this to prove Theorem 1.1. Below stated is Fact 1.10.

> **Fact 1.10** Given positive numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_k$, then $$\min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \left( \frac{a_i}{b_i} \right) \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k b_i}.$$

They said you can prove the statement using easy algebraic manipulations. I tried to prove it but I didn't manage. Am I missing something easy here ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/given-4-integers-a-b-c-d-0-does-fracab-fraccd-imply-fra, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704411/shorter-proof-of-generalized-mediant-inequality

Comment: why you posted this? question has been answered right?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac ab \leq \frac cd$ then $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ lies between these two fractions (equal to both if they are equal). To see this, note that

$a(b+d) = ab+ad \leq ab+bc \leq b(a+c)$ , and

$c(b+d) = cb+cd \geq ad+cd \geq d(a+c)$.

Now, suppose you have $\dfrac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$. WLOG, assume that $\frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{a_j}{b_j}$ if $i < j$. (This is just an ordering, it won't affect the final result.)

Since $\frac{a_2}{b_2} \geq \frac{a_1}{b_1}$, we see that $\frac{a_2 + a_1}{b_2 + b_1} \geq \frac {a_1}{b_1}$.

Since $\frac {a_3}{b_3} \geq \frac{a_2}{b_2} \geq \frac{a_2 + a_1}{b_2+b_1}$, hence $\frac{a_3+a_2+a_1}{b_3+b_2+b_1} \geq \frac{a_2+a_1}{b_2+b_1} \geq \frac{a_1}{b_1}$.

Going this way, you get the result for any index.

Comment: nice 1! thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. WLOG is a very powerful notion, it can induce a change in perspective, as I did here (and the inequality is very simple, as you can see).

Answer (score 0):

Note that :

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i \Big( \frac{a_i}{b_i} \Big) $$

Given that the $b_i$ are positive and:

$$ \forall i \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, k \rbrace, \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq \min \limits_{1 \leq s \leq k}\Big( \frac{a_s}{b_s} \Big) $$

you obtain:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \geq \min \limits_{1 \leq s \leq k}\Big( \frac{a_s}{b_s} \Big)\Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i \Big). $$

Comment: thanks! $\phantom{testestss}$

Answer (score 0):

A remark that gives an intuitive meaning about the inequality and could be turned into a proof (using a result on convex hulls).

Let us associate to $(a_k,b_k)$ complex number $a_k+ib_k=r_ke^{i\theta_k}$.

Their center of gravity is $\tfrac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^k a_k + i \sum_{k=1}^k b_k\right)=re^{i\theta}$.

The given inequality asserts that $\min \tan{\theta_k} \leq \tan{\theta}$, which is equivalent, because $\tan$ is an increasing function, to:

$$\min \theta_k \leq \theta$$

which is graphically evident, and can be proven in a rigorous way (using the concept of convex hull).