# About minimum and maximum inequality.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima

> Let $a_i , b_i \geqslant 0$  $\forall i \in \{1 , 2 , 3 , .... , n\}$
>
> Prove that $$min\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\} \leqslant \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i} \leqslant max\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\}$$
>
> Given that $min\{...\}$ and $max\{...\}$ equals to the minimum and the maximum element in the set.

I don’t know how to deal with minimum and maximum. I would like some hints (or solution) please. Thank you.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/given-4-integers-a-b-c-d-0-does-fracab-fraccd-imply-fra

Comment: You must have $b_i > 0$, otherwise the LHS and RHS are not defined. On the other hand, the condition $a_i \ge 0$ is not needed.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2223615/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is yet another proof, which is really elementary.

We begin by observing that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}b_i 
\end{align}
From this identity we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}b_i \geq \min\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}b_i \leq \max\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i
\end{align}
Putting these two together we obtain
\begin{align}
\min\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\}\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}  \leq \max\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\}
\end{align}

Comment: This is kinda nitpicky, but we can't outright divide by $b_i$. To start with we only have $b_i \geq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, so at some point where $b_i = 0$ a term in that sum could be undefined

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: The original question itself makes no sense if some $b_i$ is zero.

Comment: @MartinR you're right, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Denote the maximum of $\frac {a_i} {b_i}$ by $c$. Then $a_i \leq cb_i$ for all $i$. Sum this over $i$ and divide by $\sum b_i$ to get the right hand inequality. The other inequality is proved similarly.