# Prove that $\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i} \leq \arg\max_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am pretty sure that I have seen this inequality before but I don't remember ever seeing a proof of it, and I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: What is the “arg” on the right-hand side? Do you mean this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704411/42969 ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to deman $b_{i} >0$. If not, take $a_{1} = -1$, $a_{2}=1$, $b_{1}=2$ and $b_{2}=-1$. You would have $\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}}{b_{1}+b_{2}}=0$, $\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}}=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{a_{2}}{b_{2}} = -1$.