# Proof of a sequence monotonicity

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, monotone-functions

There is a little problem that I worked on, but still wasn't able to prove it completely.
I would be really gratefull if you helped me with it a bit.

*Suppose*: the sequence **k**: $\{\frac{a_n}{b_n}\}$ is monotone and $b_n>0$
*Prove*: that the sequence **m**: $\{\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}\}$ is monotone as well.
I've been able to proof that:
 -if **m** is increasing $\rightarrow$ $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}}{b_1+b_2+...+b_{n-1}}\lt\frac{a_n}{b_n}$

---

For $n=1$ $\land$ **k** $\nearrow$ you get an easy proof:
 $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\lt\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} $$ $$\frac{a_1}{b_1}\lt\frac{a_{2}}{b_{2}} $$$${a_1}{b_2}\lt{a_{2}}{b_{1}} $$

---

If **m** is $\nearrow$ then:$$\frac{a_1}{b_1}\lt\frac{a_1+a_{2}}{b_1+b_{2}}$$$${a_1}(b_1+b_2)\lt({a_1+a_{2})}{b_{1}} $$$${a_1}b_1+a_1b_2\lt{a_1}b_1+a_1b_{2} $$$$a_1b_2\lt{a_2}{b_1} $$$$\downarrow$$ $$\text{Which is the thing that we assumed} $$

---

So now if you prove it for $n\text{ } \land{n+1}$ you get a full proof. (At least for an increasing sequence, but I assume the proof for a descending one will be quite simillar)

---

Also do you need to prove that if **k** is $\nearrow$ than **m** is $\nearrow$ as well?
If yes, how would you do it?

---

$$\text{Looking for your suggestions and thank you in advance!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $(a_n/b_n)$ is increasing (otherwise replace $a_n$ by $-a_n$). We want to show that
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n} \le
 \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n+a_{n+1}}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n+b_{n+1}}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
 b_{n+1}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n) \le a_{n+1}(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n)
$$
or
$$ 
\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n} \le \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \, .
$$

And that follows from  the [generalized mediant inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704411/42969), since
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n} \le \max_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} = 
\frac{a_n}{b_n} \le \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} 
$$

Comment: Alternatively, one can avoid any explicit references to mediants by noting $$i \leq n \implies \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \implies b_{n+1}a_i \leq a_{n+1}b_i.$$ (aside from that, my solution was going to be identical, so I hope you don't mind it as a comment)

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Yes, that is even simpler, you can still post it as an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I get it!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you are missing is the "mediant" inequality. The version I remember is: with all letters positive, if $ \frac{p}{q}  < \frac{r}{s}  $  then
$$ \frac{p}{q}< \frac{p+r}{q+s}   < \frac{r}{s}   $$

As they may be allowing negative numerators, care must be used in that case.