# How to prove this inequality that $\frac{\sum_ia_ix_i}{\sum_ia_iy_i}\leq\max_i\frac{x_i}{y_i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How to prove $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^na_iy_i}\leq\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{x_i}{y_i}$, where $a_i, x_i,y_i>0$ for all $i$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704411/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let j such that $x_j/y_j=max_i (x_i/y_i)$

We have $\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i a_i y_i}\leq \frac{x_j}{y_j} \Leftrightarrow \sum_i a_ix_iy_j\leq \sum_i a_i y_i x_j$

$\Leftrightarrow \sum_i a_i (y_iy_j)\left(\frac{x_j}{y_j}-\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right) \geq 0$